# Get unique values from a specific group for top N

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a "movie" dataset. I have a movie "title" column (col no 1) and a "overall_score" column (col no 13).

Apparently multiple movies has scored 10, so when I make the top 10, it only shows me all movie with score 10.

But I only want the score 10, 9, 8 and so on until 1 to appear only 3 times. I tired using the slice function but wasn't successful in that, what do you think I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
movie2 <- movie_reviews %>%
  arrange(desc(Overall)) %>% 
  group_by(uid, title) %>% 
  head(10) %>% slice(13:3)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This makes it (much) easier for people to answer your question, and greatly increases the chance that answers will be useful to you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about which movies are within the score subgroups, then you could just use `row_number` to assign a unique number per `Overall` group.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

movie_reviews <- data.frame(
  uid = 1:100,
  title = paste("title", 1:100),
  Overall = sample(1:10, 100, replace=T)
)

movie2 <- movie_reviews %>%
  group_by(Overall) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(rn < 4)%>%
  select(-rn) %>%
  arrange(Overall)

> movie2
# A tibble: 30 × 4
     uid title    Overall    rn
   <int> <chr>      <int> <int>
 1     4 title 4        1     3
 2     9 title 9        1     2
 3    64 title 64       1     1
 4    23 title 23       2     1
 5    82 title 82       2     2
 6    87 title 87       2     3
 7     8 title 8        3     3
 8    57 title 57       3     2
 9    80 title 80       3     1
10    27 title 27       4     1
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: I'd consider adding a `set.seed` part in here so its more reproducible, but good answer either way.

Comment: I'm sorry ,I'm fairly new to R , but what does set.seed do? and how does it help?

Comment: This is a good post on the subject: https://www.statology.org/set-seed-in-r/#:~:text=The%20set.,time%20you%20run%20the%20code.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Agreed. I'll add the seed.

Comment: @thehavoc My answer is based on (pseudo) random samples (see the `sample` function). The randomness is pseudo in the sense that generated values 'appear' to be  random. However if you know the start value (the seed) and the generation method, you know exactly which numbers are generated next. So if anyone wanted to replicate my answer exactly as I posted it, then you need the seed.